# Unsupported operand {-: 'list' 'float'} when sovling polynomials (Edit)

Tags: python, sympy

**EDIT** (my mistake it is a list error not a str error)

I'm not sure what my error is here.  i'm trying the find the X values for any given equation for a given Y value.

I found the solve function on sympy.org in the doc. page for "solve" one of the very first examples is this

```
eq = x2*(1/x - z2/x)
solve(eq, x)
```

so clearly solve is able to read "eq" as an equation.

I'm wanting to allow a user to input an equation "uf". Then have them input a Y value "yi" and have "solve" find the solutions to uf - yi.

I know that the problem I am having is that "uf" is being read as a string. I don't know how to get it to read it the way i want it to.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. however this is what I've come up with. I've tried using eval as well so no success.

I'm using python 3.5

```
from scipy import *
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

x = Symbol('x')   

uf = input("Enter a function: y = ")  # user inputs random function

                                            # EX: X**2    

yi = float(input("Enter yi = ")) # user inputs initial Y value

                                    # EX: 9    

print(solve(uf - yi, x))  # solves for X values at Y = yi.

                        # EX: solves for roots at X**2 - 9 , X = -3 and 3
```

Comment: `uf` is `str`, `yi` is `float`.

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: that's page is where i found the solve function. but I dont know how to fix the problem. because it gives this example >>> eq = x**2*(1/x - z**2/x)
>>> solve(eq, x)
 and it works with no "str" error.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your uf is `str` type. You need to convert it to one of the supported types as mention in [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) and poited out by @Padraic Cunningham:

> `solve(f, *symbols, **flags)`
>
> * f
>          - a single Expr or Poly that must be zero,
>          - an Equality
>          - a Relational expression or boolean
>          - iterable of one or more of the above

You could modify your code as follows:

```
uf_poly = Poly(uf)
In [86]: print(solve(uf_poly  - yi, x))
[-3.00000000000000, 3.00000000000000]
```

**EDIT**

@asmeurer suggest a better way to do it with [sympify](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html):

```
uf_symp = sympify(uf)

In [6]: print(solve(uf_symp  - yi, x))
[-3.00000000000000, 3.00000000000000]
```

Comment: thank you. i didn't realize that Expr or Poly were anything other than just short hand.

Comment: It's better to convert it to a SymPy expression using `sympify`.